# Need to call multiple api in serial order, one after the other in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I need to call multiple api in serial order one after the other in javascript. The response of one might need to act as input to other. Can someone please suggest or give a sample code.

I tried to use the .fetch() api, but finding it difficult to pass the response of one api to other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of `promises` which are returned natively by the `fetch` api, multiple requests can be chained one after another

```
var result = fetch('api/url1') // First request
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var secondId = data.someId
        return fetch('api/url2' + secondId); // Second request
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var thirdId = data.someId
        return fetch('api/url3' + thirdId); // Third request
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        // Response of third API
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error', error)
    })
```

Comment: an async `fetchJson` helper function that both fetches and awaits the .json() -ification of the result would help clean this up.

Comment: in this if one API fail all will fail so how to handle that scenario

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer has been accepted, try `async` `await` like so.

```js
(async () => {
  // first
  const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/1");
  const result1 = await res.json();
  
  console.log("Result 1", result1);
  
  // some logic ...
  
  // second 
  const res2 = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
  const result2 = await res2.json();
  
  console.log("Result 2", result2);
  // ... so on ...
})();
```